# Passing a function expression to be used as onclick handler for a button

Tags: javascript, function-expression

For a button, I need to set the function this calls, and the value used in that call, at runtime.
I can do this like so:

```
var myfunction = /* ... */
var myvalue = /* ... */
button.setAttribute ("onclick", myfunction + "('" + myvalue + "')");
```

If I try instead:

```
button.setAttribute ("onclick", function () { myfunction(myvalue));
```

Firebug gives me a

"function statement requires a name"

even though, as far as I'm aware, I'm using a function expression here.

Answer (score 4):

```
button.onclick = function() {
    myfunction(myvalue);
}
```

Using the [proper event registration method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) would be better though:

```
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    myfunction(myvalue);
}, false);
```

Comment: Using .onclick is fine - it is naturally cross-browser

Comment: As soon as you need more than one function you'll have a problem though. And recent IEs do support addEventListener.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing brace.

`button.setAttribute ("onclick", function () { myfunction(myvalue));`

should be

`button.setAttribute ("onclick", function () { myfunction(myvalue); });`

But you probably don't want to use setAttribute to set the onclick of a button, try `button.onclick = function () { myfunction(myvalue); };` instead

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering pure JavaScript:

```
function attachEvent(element, event, handler)
{
    if (element && element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent("on" + event, handler);
    }
    else if (element && element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
    }
}
```

USAGE:

```
attachEvent(button, "click", myFunction);
```

Please be noted, IE  requires `attachEvent` and `addEventListener` doesn't work on IE and works on other browser. So you have to consider both of these functions to make it **cross-browser support**.